# Unable to install packages on R 3.4.1 redhat linux

Tags: r, linux, install.packages

We recently upgraded R on our server from version 3.3.1 to 3.4.1. However, trying to install packages that I usually use (e.g. tidyr) is failing.

Version

```
version                          
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.1                         
year           2017                        
month          06                          
day            30                          
svn rev        72865                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle
```

Result when trying to install tidyr

```
install.packages("tidyr")
Installing package into ‘/home/ria.moothilal/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-        library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘stringi’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringi_1.1.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3645872 bytes (3.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyr_0.7.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 369542 bytes (360 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 360 KB

ERROR: unable to create ‘/home/ria.moothilal/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-        library/3.4/stringi’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: unable to create ‘/home/ria.moothilal/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-    library/3.4/tidyr’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpRjE7fq/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I humbly disagree with you because package installation within R is quite standard and I would consider it to fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers". Furthermore, when I posted the question I was under the impression that the fault was caused by a new version of R which would make it a dev problem. In hindsight I was wrong. Thanks for pointing out the other sites.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the problem was the server's hard drive was out of space! Did some cleaning and now downloads working as normal :-)